# Faking a call to an array for a particular index raises an exception

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

Having the following unit test:

```
public interface ITestMe
{
    object[] Values { get; }
}

[Test]
public void Test ()
{
    var sut = A.Fake<ITestMe> ();
    A.CallTo (() => sut.Values[0]).Returns (4);

    Assert.That (sut.Values[0], Is.EqualTo (4));
}
```

results in the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.SimpleBinaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression'.
at FakeItEasy.Expressions.CallExpressionParser.Parse(LambdaExpression callExpression)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.AssertThatMemberCanBeIntercepted(LambdaExpression callSpecification)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo(Expression1 callSpecification) at FakeItEasy.A.CallTo(Expression1 callSpecification)
```

Or maybe I do not know how to specify a fake for an indexer?

Comment: Why not just fake the array?  `A.CallTo(() => sut.Values).Returns(new object[]{4})`.

Comment: @CharlesMager : see my comment under Blair's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that `Values` isn't an indexer.
It's a property that returns an array.

An unconfigured `Values` will return a zero-length array (because arrays aren't fakeable). That's what's happening here, and `()=>sut.Values[0]` would fail if it were ever executed (which FakeItEasy doesn't do).

So the real takeaway here is that since `Values` is an array, which is not fakeable (see [What can be faked?](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/)), there's no way to have FakeItEasy choose a return value for a particular offset. The best that can be done is to have `Values` return an array of your choosing, as @CharlesMager suggests.  For example:

```
var myArray = new object[100];
myArray[0] = 4;
myArray[50] = 17;
A.CallTo(() => sut.Values).Returns(myArray);
```

Comment: Ok, fine for getting the first item of the array. But figure an array of 100 of items and I want to configure the 50th.

Comment: One option is 

`var myArray = new object[100];
myArray[50] = 17;
A.CallTo(() => sut.Values).Returns(myArray);`

Comment: Seems to be the way. Thought there would be a fluent syntax I was missing.

Comment: See the updated answer for a little more on how there's nothing FakeItEasy can do with arrays, as they aren't fakeable. I should've thought to have it in before.